# Audio Queue Services recording to .mp4 file, that cannot be play. And Magic Cookie issue

Tags: cocoa, aac, audioqueueservices, audioqueue

I am a newbie Mac programmer just for 3 months. I got a Audio Queue Services problem, hope anyone can help me.

I using Audio Queue Services API created a recording program, and output AAC format data. It's seems good, everything work fine.

Until I get to use the **[MP4V2](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/)** Library(an open source library) to output a .mp4 file, the problem is occur.

Problem 1:

> I use **magic cookie** as a AAC header
> to input to MP4V2 library function
> **MP4WriteSample()**. Inside the .mp4 file has data, but the
> player(ex:Quicktime) **can't** recognized
> the .mp4 file, it can't play the audio data.

---

Problem 2:

I set my audio queue basic descriptions format in following :

```
    aqData.mDataFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;  // AAC codec.
    aqData.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    aqData.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1024;
```

and use AudioQueueGetProperty() to get magic cookie.

Than I print out my **magic cookie** contants, like that:

```
    <03808080 22000000 04808080 14401500 18000001 f4000001 f4000580 80800212 10068080 800102>
```

total 39 Bytes.

> What exactly it mean?
>
> What the 39 Bytes each represented mean?
>
> Can it convert to AAC header?

*Reference :*

*[Set a Magic Cookie for an Audio File](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1)*

*[Set a Magic Cookie for a Playback Audio Queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW1)*

*[CoreAudio - how to determine the end of the playing aac file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189292/coreaudio-how-to-determine-the-end-of-the-playing-aac-file)*

---

Thanks a lot.

Ryan

Comment: Is it no one can help me? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

set file type to kAudioFileM4AType

```
AudioFileCreateWithURL (
            audioFileURL,
            kAudioFileM4AType,
            &audioFormat,
            kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
            &audioFileID
    );
```